# AES BadTag Exception when I try to decrypt in android

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt a simple string using AES encryption.
Currently I'm generating a secrect key using `KeyGenerator` and I'm generating a random IV with 16 bytes using `Secure Random`

The problem is, when I run this code:

```
  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val random = SecureRandom()
        val iv = ByteArray(12)
        random.nextBytes(iv)
        aesKeystoreAESWrapper = AES_WRAPPER()
        aesKeystoreAESWrapper.createSymmetricKey()
        val teste = aesKeystoreAESWrapper.encrypt("OLA MALTA", iv)
        val result = aesKeystoreAESWrapper.decrypt(teste, iv)


        ola.text = result

    }
```

I get a RunTime Execption: `javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException`

I can't figure out where the problem is, I tried to search in multiple websites but I couldn't find the awnser.

This is my AES code:

```
class AES_WRAPPER {

    fun ByteArray.fromBytetoString() = String(this,Charsets.UTF_8)
    companion object{
        const val AES_NOPAD_TRANS = "AES/GCM/NoPadding" //Format - ”Algorithm/Mode/Padding”
        const val ANDROID_KEYSTORE = "AndroidKeyStore"
        const val KEY_ALIAS = "Keyalaisasf"
    }

    private fun createKeyStore(): KeyStore {
        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEYSTORE)
        keyStore.load(null)
        return keyStore
    }

    @RequiresApi(23)
    fun createSymmetricKey() : SecretKey {
        try{
            val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEYSTORE)

            val keyGenParameterSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                KEY_ALIAS,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
                .build()
            keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec)
            return keyGenerator.generateKey()
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to create a symmetric key", e)
        } catch (e: NoSuchProviderException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to create a symmetric key", e)
        } catch (e: InvalidAlgorithmParameterException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to create a symmetric key", e)
        }
    }

    fun encrypt(data: String, initVector: ByteArray) : ByteArray{
        val iv = GCMParameterSpec(128, initVector)

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_NOPAD_TRANS)
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSymmetricKey(), iv)

        val encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data.toByteArray())

        return encrypted
    }

    fun decrypt(data: ByteArray, initVector: ByteArray) : String{
        val iv = GCMParameterSpec(128, initVector)

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_NOPAD_TRANS)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSymmetricKey(), iv)

        val decrypted = cipher.doFinal(data)

        return decrypted.fromBytetoString()
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    fun getSymmetricKey(): SecretKey {
        /*val keysore = keyStore.getEntry(KEY_ALIAS, null) as KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry
        return keysore.secretKey*/

        val keyStore = createKeyStore()

        if(!isKeyExists(keyStore)){
            createSymmetricKey()
        }

        return keyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS,null) as SecretKey
    }

    fun isKeyExists(keyStore : KeyStore): Boolean {
        val aliases = keyStore.aliases()
        while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            return (KEY_ALIAS == aliases.nextElement())
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

**UPDATE, LOGCAT:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.github.andre00nogueira.myapplication, PID: 10135
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.github.andre00nogueira.myapplication/io.github.andre00nogueira.myapplication.MainActivity}: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:517)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
        at io.github.andre00nogueira.myapplication.WRAPPER.decrypt(WRAPPER.kt:73)
        at io.github.andre00nogueira.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Signature/MAC verification failed
        at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1292)
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:224)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreAuthenticatedAESCipherSpi$BufferAllOutputUntilDoFinalStreamer.doFinal(AndroidKeyStoreAuthenticatedAESCipherSpi.java:373)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:506)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The unmodified code is executed on my machine without any problems, especially the decryption works (Android P, API Level 28 as well as Android O, API Level 27).

Comment: Really? This is my logcat, running on API 29, please see the updated version

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an old key with the given alias but with different properties? (side note: there's a `containsAlias` method, so you don't have to iterate over all the aliases).

Comment: The logic in `isKeyExists` only works reliably if there is exactly one alias in the store. If there are more, it is aborted after the first iteration and the result is determined by the first alias. Instead of the first `return` statement there should be something like `if (KEY_ALIAS == aliases.nextElement()) return true`. That should be it, because this will generate different keys for encryption and decryption, right?

Comment: If Michael's suggestion is used, i.e. `isKeyExists(keyStore)` is replaced by `keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_ALIAS)`, the problem solves itself.

Comment: @Topaco Can you please post answers? This basically solves the issue. Please let the question get an answered so it can be marked answered. Then people like me don't have to read all of question and comments just to find out what the state is. This is getting annoying, I'm really happy to upvote answers. I'm also happy to start flagging to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `isKeyExists()` function, which should check if `KEY_ALIAS` is contained in the keystore. However, the current implementation only checks the *first* alias found by `aliases.nextElement()` against `KEY_ALIAS` and returns with this result. Therefore this function only works reliably if there is exactly one alias in the keystore. With more than one alias this leads to a *false negative* result if `KEY_ALIAS` is in the keystore but not found as first by `aliases.nextElement()`. As a consequence, different keys are created for encryption and decryption, which raises the *AEADBadTagException* during decryption.

The problem can be solved if in `isKeyExists()` the return statement in the while loop is replaced by

```
if (KEY_ALIAS == aliases.nextElement()) return true
```

or alternatively, as suggested in Michael's comment, if `isKeyExists(keyStore)` is replaced by [`keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_ALIAS)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/security/KeyStore#containsAlias(kotlin.String)) in `getSymmetricKey()`.